# Trying to not show v-model change until I want to show it

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Okay so I have a table and the table has a number display and an Input for the user to increase the number up and down.

```
<tr v-for="(obj, index) in OBJECTARRAY" :key="obj.key">
    <td>{{OBJOTHERNUMBER- OBJNUMBER}}</td>
    <td>
        <input v-model="OBJNUMBER" type="number">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I don't want this change to show dynamically with a v-model but with a button click that updates the change?

Comment: Have you tried using :value instead of v-model with your @change event?

Comment: fyi - With this approach make sure to set the value inside of your function that is called from your @change event. It will no longer dynamically update when using :value

Comment: Thanks for updating with the additional code! Looks like BTL's answer is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ref to access the input value and set the discountPrice when the update button is clicked. In Vue it's best practice to not access the document directly. Not sure if you want a button for each row or a bulk update so I've included both. Here's the codepen if you want to see it in action https://codepen.io/madison_at_vrume/pen/mdWNrMy

```
<div>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(obj, index) in prices" :key="obj.key">
      <td>{{ obj.salePrice - obj.discountPrice }}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          :ref="`discountInput-${index}"
          :value="obj.discountPrice"
          type="number"
        >
      </td>
      <td>
      <button @click="updatePrice(index)">Update Price</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
    
  <button @click="updateAllPrices()">Update Prices</button>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
  updatePrice(index) {
    const newDiscountPrice = this.$refs[`discountInput-${index}`].value;
      this.prices[index].discountPrice = newDiscountPrice;
    },
  updateAllPrices() {
    this.prices.forEach((obj, index) => {
      this.updatePrice(index);
    })
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use 2 variables.

- `DiscountPriceTemp`
- `DiscountPrice`

And when you click on the button, you update `DiscountPrice` with `DiscountPriceTemp`.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(obj, index) in OBJECTARRAY" :key="obj.key">
    <td>{{ obj.SalePrice - obj.DiscountPrice }}</td>
    <td>
      <input v-model="obj.DiscountPriceTemp" type="number">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onButtonClick (obj) {
      obj.DiscountPrice = obj.DiscountPriceTemp
    }
  }
}
```